# Plot shapefiles with geometry point and line on a single plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, geopandas

I have 3 shapefiles that I want to layer/ superimpose on top of each other, so all the plots can be viewed on a single map. I have [bus stops](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/RPCGB::bus-stops/data?geometry=-87.884%2C33.312%2C-85.798%2C33.713&page=26), [bus routes](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/RPCGB::birmingham-area-transit-routes-1?geometry=-87.879%2C33.312%2C-85.793%2C33.713), and a [zone map](https://data-jeffco-al.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/zoning-map-for-jefferson-county-al/data?geometry=-87.453%2C33.444%2C-86.410%2C33.644) in each of the shapefiles. When attempting to plot the route on the zone, the plot is easily achieved using the code below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,20))

ZoneMap.plot(ax=ax, alpha = 0.2, color = 'blue')
ExistingRoutesMap.plot(ax=ax,color = 'green', label = 'bus routes')

plt.show()
```

[image]

When I try to map the bus stops on top of the zone and the route, the map gets skewed, and all points are piled up in a corner of a map because it looks like the scales are off.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,20))

ZoneMap.plot(ax=ax, alpha = 0.2, color = 'blue')
ExistingRoutesMap.plot(ax=ax,color = 'green', label = 'bus routes')
BJCTABusStops.plot(ax=ax, color = 'orange', label = 'bus stops')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If I plot the stops alone, without the zone and route layers, I see the below plot, which follows the exact shape of the routes:

[image]

How can I correct this issue and have all the maps show together on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I used

```
BJCTABusStops = gpd.read_file(r'Bus_Stops-shp\Bus_Stops.shp')
ExistingRoutesMap = gpd.read_file(r'Birmingham_Area_Transit_Routes-shp\Birmingham_Area_Transit_Routes.shp')
ZoneMap = gpd.read_file(r'Zoning_Map_for_Jefferson_County%2C_AL\Zoning_Map_for_Jefferson_County%2C_AL.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,20))
ZoneMap.plot(ax=ax, alpha = 0.2, color = 'blue')
ExistingRoutesMap.plot(ax=ax,color = 'green', label = 'bus routes')
BJCTABusStops.plot(ax=ax, color = 'orange', label = 'bus stops')
plt.show()
```

Produce this map for me

[image]

Did you correctly upload the data and sure that you haven't modified ?

Comment: Hey, I think the data upload had an issue, I reloaded the data from the links and it works just fine now. Thank you so much!